# Setting up Google Cloud Printer Server via CUPS

Tags: printing, cloud, google

I am trying to set up a Google Cloud Printer Server using CUPS Connector on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 computer.  My two printers are WiFi printers, but does not support e-printing, which is my goal to be able to print on my Android devices when I am not connected to the same network.

I am following the steps explained [here](https://github.com/google/cups-connector/wiki/Install).

I downloaded the `gcp-cups-connector-linux-amd64-2015.10.05.tar.gz` binary and extracted it to `/home/username/Downloads/cups-connector`

I installed the dependencies without any issues.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcups2 libavahi-client3 avahi-daemon git bzr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
avahi-daemon is already the newest version.
libavahi-client3 is already the newest version.
bzr is already the newest version.
git is already the newest version.
libcups2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

The issue that I am having is when I am trying to run `gcp-cups-connector`

```
$ gcp-cups-connector
gcp-cups-connector: command not found
```

I appreciate any advice on helping me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
./gcp-cups-connector
```

or

```
~/Downloads/cups-connector/gcp-cups-connector
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running on ubuntu 64 bit.

You need to do this.

First, download the correct package (Ubuntu is based on Debian):

```
wget https://github.com/google/cups-connector/releases/download/2016.01.02/gcp-cups-connector-debian-8-amd64-2016.01.02.tar.gz
tar xvf gcp-cups-connector-rpi-jessie-2016.01.02.tar.gz
```

Next, set an alias for the files:

```
echo 'alias gcp-cups-connector="~/cups-connector/gcp-cups-connector"' | tee -a ~/.bashrc
echo 'alias gcp-cups-connector-util="~/cups-connector/gcp-cups-connector-util"' | tee -a ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now, you should be able to run the commands.